# DIY Stucco Repair on a 100 year old brick rowhome

Tags: brick, old-house, stucco

Hello fellow home improvement masochists.

My partner and I are in a 100 year old rowhome in South Philadelphia, and we have a rear exterior wall that is stucco over brick in need of some repair. There are some pretty minor cracks, but in a maybe half foot wide, 3 foot tall section behind a fence post there is some exposed brick with a significant amount of mortar missing and some deep (like I can reach my hand in there) gaps at ground level.

I've had 2 people out to give us some very expensive options for either completely replacing the stucco, repairing the worst spots, and replacing with siding (very expensive!). My questions is: am I able to repair this kind of this myself? Is it wise to try and DIY the missing spots in the brick? What materials and tools and techniques would I need? I'm truly starting from less than zero here.[image][image]